# Where can I get symfony third party bundles with full configuration and explanation?

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony framework so I don't have idea about bundles so I want to use third party bundles.

To get third party bundles as per my functionality I refer [this](http://symfony.com/blog/the-30-most-useful-symfony-bundles-and-making-them-even-better) and [this](https://github.com/sitepoint/awesome-symfony) links but I can't get full explanation about bundles like how to use , after install third party bundles where I need to change , which and where I need to configuration ?

So can anyone from symfony community guide me to how to use third party bundles ? and how to configure ? and where I need to configure ? configure mean routing.yml , config.yml file changes.

for ex : I need to install page building Bundle (CMS) for static pages (like about us , privacy and policy etc.) I install 3 different bundles using composer from  git hub but none of are working. At last I install [BeelabSimplePageBundle](https://github.com/Bee-Lab/BeelabSimplePageBundle) bundle and it install successfully in my vendor folder but on github there is not so much explanation about routing , configuration. may be some pro symfony developer can understand that explanation but newbie like me can't understand it because there is not step by step explanation.

so if there is any pro symfony developer please explain  BeelabSimplePageBundle step by step and full explaination for install and for any third party bundle.so next time when I need to add any third party bundle I can do it myself and if needed I can explain to some newbie developer in future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every bundle must come with its own documentation. The one you asked about comes with documentation, so just check it.

Comment: yes, and if bundle is not coming with documentation, probably it is not worth using, as it can compromise your whole production app. but usually you just add necessary third party code via composer. You can read more about it on https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party bundles usually comes with it's own documentation. If it doesn't you should avoid using it because it is going to make the development process harder and make your code buggy.

1. Only choose well documented and reputed bundles
2. Use the original documentation that comes with the bundle

In case you are needing a good place to search for symfony bundles, [knpbundles.com](http://knpbundles.com/) has a large collection of symfony bundles

Comment: does anyone provide paid Bundle with support so if we can't figure out something they can help us? Any website who is provide paid Bundle with well documentation and support for Symfony ?

Comment: I've personally not used any paid bundle and there also doesn't seem to be any decent provider.If you're really new to the framework you should better get familiar with it before adding a lot of third party bundles. Adding lot of bundles without good understanding about symfony can also lead to confusion